# Define block diagrams with vhdl or some other language

Tags: diagrams

Is it possible to use vhdl in LaTeX code to get block diagrams?

```
    \package{vhdltoblockdiagram}
% ...
    \begin{vhdl}
% entity Comp is generic ( n : natural := 2 );
% port (
%    A       : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
%    B       : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
%    greater : out std_logic;
%    less    : out std_logic;
%--bottom--
%    equal   : out std_logic;
%);
%end Comp;
    \end{vhdl}
```

Result like here:
http://vhdltolatex.mamikon.net/

How can I define block diagrams without telling the position of the elements? I would like an automatical layout.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know vhdl, hence I'm not sure this is an answer your question.

If you want to change the diagram because you have more/less element before or after the `item` node, you have only to add/remove elements from the left/right matrices, change the factor who divide `\myheight` and adjust the `\foreach` conditions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\myheight}{2.5cm}
\tikzset{labels/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    circuit/.style={draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=\myheight,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    triangle 45/.tip={Triangle[angle=45:8pt]}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>=triangle 45]
        \node [circuit] (item) {Comp};
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes, 
            left= of item, 
            row sep=\myheight/5,
            nodes={anchor=east}
            ] (rightmatr) { 
            A\\
            B\\
        };
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes, 
            right= of item, 
            row sep=\myheight/6,
            nodes={anchor=west}
            ] (leftmatr) { 
            greater\\
            less\\
            equal\\
        };
        \foreach \i in {1,2}
            \draw [->] (rightmatr-\i-1) -- (rightmatr-\i-1 -| item.west);
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
            \draw [<-] (leftmatr-\i-1) -- (leftmatr-\i-1 -| item.east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Entity of Comp}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]