# labels in tikz like shown in the example

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a follow-up of my previous question: [Define block diagrams with vhdl or some other language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403090/define-block-diagrams-with-vhdl-or-some-other-language).

Is there any possibility to get the labels IN the square? Like here:

[image]

An also write some text on the connection line?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\myheight}{2.5cm}
\tikzset{labels/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    circuit/.style={draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=\myheight,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    triangle 45/.tip={Triangle[angle=45:8pt]}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>=triangle 45]
        \node [circuit] (item) {Comp};
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes, 
            left= of item, 
            row sep=\myheight/5,
            nodes={anchor=east}
            ] (rightmatr) { 
            A\\
            B\\
        };
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes, 
            right= of item, 
            row sep=\myheight/6,
            nodes={anchor=west}
            ] (leftmatr) { 
            greater\\
            less\\
            equal\\
        };
        \foreach \i in {1,2}
            \draw [->] (rightmatr-\i-1) -- (rightmatr-\i-1 -| item.west);
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
            \draw [<-] (leftmatr-\i-1) -- (leftmatr-\i-1 -| item.east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Entity of Comp}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 1):

I would use simple tikz commands like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\myheight}{2.5cm}
\tikzset{labels/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    circuit/.style={draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=\myheight,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    triangle 45/.tip={Triangle[angle=45:8pt]}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>=triangle 45]

          \path[draw,ultra thick] (0,0) node (A){} --(0,4) node (B){}-- (3,4) node (C){} --(3,0) node (D){}--cycle;

          \node (cent) at (1.5,2){\large Comp};
          \node[right] (AB1) at (0,1){A};
          \node[right] (AB2) at (0,3){B};
          \node[left] (CD1) at (3,1) {less};
          \node[left] (CD2) at (3,3) {greater};
          \node[above] (AD) at (1.5,0) {equal};

          \node (A1) at (-2,1) {input};
          \node (A2) at (-2,3) {input};
          \node (C1) at (5,1) {output};
          \node (C2) at (5,3) {output};
          \node (D1) at (5,-1) {output};


          \draw[->] (A1)--(AB1);
          \draw[->] (A2)--(AB2);
          \draw[->] (CD1)--(C1);
          \draw[->] (CD2)--(C2);
          \draw[->] (AD)|-(D1);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Entity of Comp}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is almost your requested (Sorry... not screenshot on this pc)

Of course you can automate some of th commands if you want to use them many times

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the flexibility you seemed to need in your previous question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta} 
\newlength{\myheight} 
\setlength{\myheight}{3cm} 
\tikzset{labels/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    description/.style={font=\scriptsize, below, text centered, text width=4em}, 
    circuit/.style={draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=\myheight,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,font=\sffamily\bfseries}, triangle 45/.tip={Triangle[angle=45:8pt]} } 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[htb] 
        \centering 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>=triangle 45] 
        \node [circuit] (item) {Comp}; 
        \matrix[ 
            matrix of nodes, 
            nodes in empty cells,
            left=7em of item, row sep=\myheight/6, nodes={anchor=east} ] (leftmatr) 
            {input\\  \\ input\\ }; 
        \matrix[ 
            nodes in empty cells,
            matrix of nodes, 
            right=7em of item, row sep=\myheight/6, nodes={anchor=west} ] (rightmatr) { output\\ \\ output \\}; 
        \foreach \i/\mylab\mydescr in {1/A/{some text \\ for A}, 
                                       3/B/{some text \\ for B}} 
            {\draw [->] (leftmatr-\i-1) -- (leftmatr-\i-1 -| item.west) 
                node[right, labels] {\mylab}
                node[midway,description] {\mydescr};} 
        \foreach \i/\mylab\mydescr in {1/greater/{some text \\ for greater},
                                       3/less/{some text \\ for less}} 
            {\draw [<-] (rightmatr-\i-1) -- (rightmatr-\i-1 -| item.east) 
                node[left, labels] {\mylab}
                node[midway,description] {\mydescr};}
        \node[below=3ex of rightmatr] (out3) {output};
        \draw[<-] (out3) -| (item.south) node[above, labels] {equal}
            node[near start,description] {some text \\ for equal};
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{Entity of Comp} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the text above the lines instead of below, just put `above` instead of `below` in the `description` style:

```
description/.style={font=\scriptsize, above, text centered, text width=4em},
```

and you'll get this:

[image]

Moreover, I highly recommend to read Section 3 here: [The DuckBoat -- News from TeX.SE: Asking effective questions](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

A node like this can be drawn with a simple rectangular node with as many `labels` as you need. There's no need for matrices.

In following code I've used `quotes` library to define the labels. And as they are `named` nodes, you can later on use as refernce for your arrows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta, quotes}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\myheight}{2.5cm}
\tikzset{labels/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    circuit/.style={draw, 
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=2.5cm,
        very thick,
        inner sep=1mm,
        outer sep=0pt,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    triangle 45/.tip={Triangle[angle=45:8pt]}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>=triangle 45]
        \node[circuit,
            "north west:A" {anchor=west, labels, yshift=-5mm, name=A},
            "north east:greater" {anchor=east, labels, yshift=-5mm, name=greater},
            "south west:B" {anchor=west, labels, yshift=5mm, name=B},
            "south east:less" {anchor=east, labels, yshift=5mm, name=less},
            "south:equal" {anchor=south, labels, name=equal}] (comp) {Comp};
        \draw[<-] (A.west)--node[above]{A}++(180:1cm) node[left]{input};
        \draw[<-] (B.west)--node[above]{B}++(180:1cm) node[left]{input};
        \draw[->] (greater.east)--node[above]{C}++(0:1cm) node (out) [right]{output};
        \draw[->] (less.east)--node[above]{D}++(0:1cm) node[right]{output};
        \draw[->] (equal.south)--++(-90:5mm) coordinate(aux) -- node[below]{E} (aux-|out.west) node[right]{output};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Entity of Comp}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did all those complicate things because in the other question the OP wrote _How can I define block diagrams without telling the position of the elements? I would like an automatical layout._ But it's likely I don't understand what the OP meant.